# UiPickerView over UiToolBar - Swift 4 Upgrade Error

Tags: uipickerview, uitoolbar, swift4, xcode9

I updated my project to `Swift` 4 `XCode` 9
I have a InputText whit a input view using a Picker
I added a `UIToolBar` at InputText. 
It was working well before upgrade. 
now it's like the `UIPickerView` it's over the `UIToolBar`.

I can see but if i click on it's like I click on `UIPickerView`

The `UIToolBar` it's perfectly working, because if i set the toolbar to a normal TextInput it appear and work well..

What can be?

**Here is my code:**

```
var picker: UIPickerView
picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: view.frame.width, height: 300))
picker.backgroundColor = .white

picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
picker.delegate = self
picker.dataSource = PickerData as? UIPickerViewDataSource


textField.inputView = picker

let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
toolBar.isTranslucent = true
toolBar.tintColor = .blue
toolBar.sizeToFit()

let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Seleziona", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneFunction(_:)))
let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Annulla", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneFunction(_:)))

toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

I tried also with `picker.addSubview(toolBar)` but whit same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and I solved it with a background view and adding 2 subviews on it - picker and toolbar.
Here is the code:

```
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = green
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: toolBar.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.width, height: 300))
    picker.tintColor = green
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self

    let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: view.frame.width, height: 300 + toolBar.frame.size.height))

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(nextPicker))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelPicker))
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    bgView.addSubview(picker)
    bgView.addSubview(toolBar)
    cell.textField.inputView = bgView
```

Hopefully it helped.